# How to substring a String in java when it has Double bytes chracters

Tags: java, arrays, byte, substring

I have a string that might contain both Unicode and UTF-8 characters. This makes it difficult when I want to save them to a database that doesn't deal with Unicode characters. The database I am using is PostgreSQL. They might be to big for a certain column this is a simple example for my situation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test= "İİİİİİİİİİ";
    byte[] bytesOrig = null;
    bytesOrig = test.getBytes("UTF-8");
    System.out.println("bytesOrig="+new String(bytesOrig));
    byte[] bytesFive = new byte[5];

    System.arraycopy(bytesOrig, 0, bytesFive, 0, 5);
    System.out.println("bytes-Five="+new String(bytesFive));
    System.out.println("Substring="+test.substring(0,5));
    System.out.println("Substring real length=" + test.substring(0,5).getBytes().length);
}
```

I cant use the String.substring method since it will NOT help me in case of double bytes characters - i have tried working with Bytes-Array copy but it means that the last characters might be deleted.

And this is the Debug info:

```
    bytesOrig=İİİİİİİİİİ
    bytes-Five=İİ�
    Substring=İİİİİ
    Substring real length=10
```

You can see since I have only part of the Bytes array - I don't want the last character to appear as �

Comment: Why do you want to use substring? To truncate the string to the size of the column? Which database are you using? You may want to change the table so that it supports Unicode, or counts the size in characters, not bytes. That would be better than truncating values.

Comment: i am working with PostgreSQL DB. i cant force the DB column to be Unicode.

Comment: PostgreSQL, when the table is defined properly, would take characters as characters. That is, "İİİİİ" is exactly 5 characters long even if it is more in bytes, and will be accepted by a varchar(5) column. If your database doesn't accept unicode you shouldn't be using it to store unicode - you'll get compatibility issues and gibberish from various applications.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, good explanation! If you store the java string (which is UTF-16) as binary in the database (as a dumb storage), would there be any problem (other than not being able to use the column in SQL queries, ofcourse)?

Comment: @blackpen Storing data in binary in a binary column is always possible - the database doesn't care that it was originally a string. But if the binary store is fixed-length, you better make sure it is double the number of characters you have (assuming you save as UTF-16).

Comment: @RealSkeptic, Agreed. I also see that there is no point in storing it as binary, since, you can't query it. That solution works for everythigng ... images, video (So, in effect, it is a no-solution!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the logic is done at **transformOverhead** method
according to the value, we will increase i.

```
public class ZoneTrimTransformer implements ZoneTransformer {

private int maxLength;

public ZoneTrimTransformer(int maxLength) {
    this.maxLength = maxLength;
}

@Override
public Object transform(Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        String val = value.toString();
        if (getDBRequireLength(val) > getJavaLength(val) ){
            return transformOverhead(val);
        }
        else if (val != null && getJavaLength(val) > maxLength) {

            // Trim
            val = val.substring(0, maxLength);
        }

        return val;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("1234567".substring(0, 5));
}

public  int getJavaLength(String val) {
    return val.length();
}

public  int getDBRequireLength(String val) {
    return val.getBytes().length;
}

private  Object transformOverhead(Object s) {
    byte[] byeArray = s.toString().getBytes();
    if (byeArray.length < maxLength) maxLength = byeArray.length;
    int n16 = 0;
    int advance = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < maxLength) {
        advance = 1;
        if ((byeArray[i] & 0x80) == 0) i += 1;
        else if ((byeArray[i] & 0xE0) == 0xC0) i += 2;
        else if ((byeArray[i] & 0xF0) == 0xE0) i += 3;
        else { i += 4; advance = 2; }
        if (i <= maxLength) n16 += advance;
    }
    return s.toString().substring(0,n16);
    }
}
```

And a test class for it:

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ZoneTrimTransformerTest {



@Test
public void testLengths()
{
    ZoneTrimTransformer lztr = new ZoneTrimTransformer(5);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("İİİİİİİİİİ"),"İİ");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(lztr.transform("İİİİİİİİİİ").toString()),4);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(lztr.transform("İİİİİİİİİİ").toString()),2);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("%&*%$^&$$^&$").toString(),"%&*%$");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("%&*%$^&$$^&$").toString()),12);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("%&*%$^&$$^&$").toString()),12);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("媒体アカウント名"),"媒");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("媒体アカウント名").toString()),24);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("媒体アカウント名").toString()),8);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("媒体媒体アカウント名アカウント名"),"媒");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("媒体媒体アカウント名アカウント名").toString()),48);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("媒体媒体アカウント名アカウント名").toString()),16);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("SÄ°STA+UNÄ°VERSAL"),"SÄ°");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("SÄ°STA+UNÄ°VERSAL").toString()),21);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("SÄ°STA+UNÄ°VERSAL").toString()),17);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("1234567890"),"12345");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("1234567890").toString()),10);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("1234567890").toString()),10);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("abcdefghI"),"abcde");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("abcdefghI").toString()),9);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("abcdefghI").toString()),9);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("אהגדהוזחט"),"אה");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("אהגדהוזחט").toString()),18);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("אהגדהוזחט").toString()),9);

    assertEquals(lztr.transform("ABAA"),"ABAA");
    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(("ABAA").toString()),4);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(("ABAA").toString()),4);


    assertEquals(lztr.getDBRequireLength(lztr.transform("ABCE").toString()),4);
    assertEquals(lztr.getJavaLength(lztr.transform("ABCE").toString()),4);



}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: the changing places are shows in comment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String test= "İİİİİİİİİİ";
    System.out.println("test.length() = " + test.length()); // out: 10
    byte[] bytesOrig;
    bytesOrig = test.getBytes("UTF-8"); // but after get bytes will return 20
    System.out.println("bytesOrig.length = " + bytesOrig.length); // it
    System.out.println("bytesOrig="+new String(bytesOrig));
    byte[] bytesFive = new byte[10]; // 1. so change here to twice

    System.arraycopy(bytesOrig, 0, bytesFive, 0, 10); // 2. change here also
    System.out.println("bytes-Five="+new String(bytesFive));
    System.out.println("Substring="+test.substring(0,5));
    System.out.println("Substring real length=" + test.substring(0,5).getBytes().length);
}
```

And here is the output:

```
test.length() = 10
bytesOrig.length = 20
bytesOrig=İİİİİİİİİİ
bytes-Five=İİİİİ
Substring=İİİİİ
Substring real length=10
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the problem. It's not about *displaying* the correct substring. It's about transferring no more than 5 bytes to the database, without getting a split character at the end.

Comment: I detected the problem when I got the length of the `bytesOrig`

Comment: I have test your solution with  %&*%$^&$$^&$  (punctuation) and it dosnt work - the last character is converted into weird characters such as �